Stein Real Analysis chapter 5 exercise 14
Problem: Suppose $F$ and $G$ are two integrable functions on a bounded interval $[a,b]$. Show that $G$ is the weak derivative of $F$ if and only if $F$ can be corrected on a set of measure $0$, such that $F$ is absolutely continuous and $F'(x) = G(x)$ for almost every x.
The sufficiency is obvious, but as for the necessity, even after seeing the hint, I still do not know how to prove F is absolutely continuous and its derivative is G. And as for the hint, what can we get from that approximation?

If $L(F) = G$, then we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}G\cdot \varphi \, dx = -\int_{a}^{b}F\cdot \varphi' \, dx ~~\text{for any $\varphi \in C_0^{\infty}(a,b)$}
\end{equation}
With the formula of integration by parts, we have
\begin{aligned}
    \int_a^b G \cdot \varphi \, dx &= \left[ \int_a^x G(t) \, dt \cdot \varphi \right]_a^b - \int_a^b \left(\int_a^x G(t) \, dt\right) \cdot \varphi' \, dx \\
    &= - \int_a^b \left(\int_a^x G(t) \, dt\right) \cdot \varphi' \, dx.
\end{aligned}
Thus we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b} \left( F - \int_a^x G(t) \, dt \right) \, \varphi'dx = 0 ~~\text{for any $\varphi' \in C_0^{\infty}(a,b)$}
\end{equation}
So $F(x) = \int_a^x G(t) \, dt$ for a.e $x$.~~$\Longrightarrow F$ is absolutely continuous (for G is integrable)
And $F'(x) = G(x)$ for a.e $x$ (by Lebesgue differential theorem)

I now complete the proof without the use of the hint, and I wonder how can we prove it with that hint in the book
